# How to know the per-chip default value of a linux module

Tags: linux, module

I'm trying tune my laptops video(Intel HD 520), in reference to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics

`modinfo -p i915` shows module parameters that can be set.
Some of the parameters says that the default value is per-chip.

```
enable_fbc:Enable frame buffer compression for power savings (default:-1 (use per-chip default)) (int)
```

How can I know whats the per-chip default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the kernel *without* changing the parameter, and look at `/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_fbc`. That will tell you the default on the running kernel version for the hardware you're running it on.

Otherwise, you can only really tell by looking at the i915 driver sources for the kernel version you want. The defaults get changed over time. Generally it's only enabled by default if it's safe to use, and changing this module parameter will taint the kernel. That means the developers don't care about bugs you may see when you've enabled something that was disabled by default for a reason.

Comment: Sorry to be late. Thanks you :)